# How to do GetRouteUrl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url-routing, webforms-routing

I want open "aspnet.pdf" file but in url show "Report.pdf" do not show the original file name on url please help me how i can do this.
This is on click event

```
 dr.Read();
                 filePath = dr[1] + ".pdf";
                 string fn = Server.MapPath("~/" + filePath);
                 string s = GetRouteUrl("lst", new { type = "Report.pdf" });
                 Response.Redirect(s);
```

this is in Global.asax

```
void reg_route(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection rc)
    {
        filePath = "aspnet.pdf";
        rc.MapPageRoute("lst", "{type}", "~/"+filePath);
    }
```

This is give error

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
> changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
>
> Requested URL:    localhost:2127/Report.pdf
>
> Physical Path:  C:...\WebSites\GetScheduled\Report.pdf